# What is the number of ways of selecting $r$ things from $n$ groups such that from each group at most $1$ thing can be selected ??

Tags: combinatorics

For example we've $n$ groups of sphere where $1$st group contains $n_1$ spheres of radius $a_1$, $2$nd group contains $n_2$ spheres of radius $a_2$ and so on. How many ways are there to select $r$ spheres (out of all the available spheres) such that each sphere will have unique radius??

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether spheres of common radii are distinct or not. If they are indistinct, then its simply $_n C_r$ ways to choose r items from your n categories. But if they are distinct, then the total will be the sum of all products with exactly r terms in $a_n$, since you are choosing a set of r radii to pick form out of n, and in each set, you can choose independently $r_k$ choices, where k is each of the r terms picked. This is equivalent to the r+1 th coefficient in the polynomial $(x+a_1)(x+a_2)...(x+a_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $n$ *independent* choices, with $n_1$ possibilities for the first choice, $n_2$ possibilities for then 2nd choice, etc. So: 
$\prod\limits_{1=1}^n n_i$

Comment: We are selecting $r$ spheres from $n$ groups of spheres.  Your answer is correct for the special case $r = n$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - Yeah, I apparently missed it was $r$ choices when I answered this nearly 4 years ago.